# Rails how to loop to get just one item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How to loop to get just one item of the table?

if you use

```
<% @blocks.first(4).each do |b| %>
```

will get the first 4 of the table

but to get just the item 5?

i've tried using find `<% @blocks.find(5).each do |b| %>`

but keep getting the firsts 5 of the table

so, someone know?

inside block

```
<% @blocks.first(1).each do |b| %>

  <li >

    <%= link_to  content_tag(:span, b.category),  block_path(:id => b.id), :class => "drop" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can you post a `puts @blocks`

Comment: sorry i did not get

Comment: What is `@blocks`?

Comment: What do you have in `@blocks`

Comment: is it `@blocks = Block.all`

Comment: sorry i did not get what you mean

Comment: You gotta give us something... The question is unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *need* the loop to get one item. You can just get it directly:

```
 <% b = @blocks[4] # fifth element %>
```

But if, for whatever reason, you *do* want the loop, you can use drop / take.

```
<% @blocks.drop(4).take(1).each do |b| %>
```

Note: This assumes `Array` interface. If your `@blocks` is something else, different solutions might be available.

Comment: that's it. i did not understood how to use this b = @blocks[4]